# How can I extract a value from a WMI object and store it in a variable?

Tags: python, wmi

I want to query WMI and store values in some variables. The result returns a WMI Object, I need the value on its own.

I have thought about converting the WMI Object to a string, then searching through it but that doesn't seem right.

If possible, I'd like to select a value by naming the field/caption. Similar to the way you can select a value from a JSON object.

**A short example:**

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

for baseboard in c.Win32_Baseboard(["Product"]):
  print(baseboard)

baseboard_name = baseboard["Product"]
print(baseboard_name)
```

In the example above, I get this error:

> '_wmi_object' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: If you check `for baseboard in c.Win32_Baseboard(): print( baseboard )` then  you can see that simple `baseboard_name = baseboard.Product` should work…

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ, that's  much more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive Googling, I found a way to get any WMI information on its own (without the column name).

The example below shows you how to get the motherboard model:

```
import win32com.client

wmi_service = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
wbem_service = wmi_service.ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2")
baseboard_items = wbem_service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Baseboard")

for obj_item in baseboard_items:
  baseboard_name = obj_item.Product

print(baseboard_name)
```